# Spring Boot instance of app engine keeps reconnecting to postgres google sql

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Im running Spring boot application on google app engine and the other day the app crashed causing the restart of the app. Looking into logs I noticed that apps keeps repeatedly connecting to my google sql postgres database.

Looking into logs from database i can see i have 60 connections on database. Im connecting to database with cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory  simple using JDBC url:
`dbc:postgresql://google/{databaseName}?useSSL=false&cloudSqlInstance={instanceUrl}&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user={user}&password={password}`

Displayed logs are:

```
A  2019-04-11 14:57:01.674  INFO 1 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory      : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [{instance url}] on IP [{ip adress}].

A  2019-04-11 14:58:11.458  INFO 1 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [{instance url}] via ssl socket.

A  2019-04-11 14:58:11.460  INFO 1 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory      : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [{instance url}] on IP [{ip adress}].

A  2019-04-11 14:58:22.878  INFO 1 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [{instance url}] via ssl socket.

A  2019-04-11 14:58:22.880  INFO 1 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory      : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [{instance url}] on IP [{ip adress}].

A  2019-04-11 15:01:56.477  INFO 1 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance  [{instance url}] via ssl socket.

A  2019-04-11 15:01:56.479  INFO 1 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory      : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance  [{instance url}] on IP [{ip adress}].

A  2019-04-11 15:02:08.108  INFO 1 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [{instance url}] via ssl socket.
```

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended that the Project in the app engine, have at least Ram 2 gb for avoid Connection Error, you can review any code issues in this url:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-external-app.